# What terminal command can I tell Mac OS X:s software-firewall to block all incoming connections?

Tags: networking, mac, terminal, firewall

I want to script the turning on and off of the "block all incoming connections"-function of the built-in firewall in OS X. What terminal-command would achieve this?

I'm not talking about `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf globalstate -int 0` to turn the firewall on, but specifically about the "block all incoming connections"-option which is available in the GUI under "Firewall Options…" in "System Preferences".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://krypted.com/mac-security/command-line-firewall-management-in-os-x-10-10/) amongst all sorts of firewall related scripting instructions.

It's `/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setblockall on`